Why does Google not like my structured data
This is for the web page https://louishowe-dev.azurewebsites.net/Organization/Profile?id=30015&crawler=true

Google's Schema Markup Validator is able to read all the data. (so good)
Google's Rich Results Test finds no items. - why not?

It appears to have the data there:


It needs the address property. Without that it decides the structured data is unusable.

You can improve your answer by explaining it with an example and/or providing a reference
